# Cannot access virtual hosts between containers with docker-compose using nginx-proxy and dnsmasq

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, dnsmasq

### Context

I was planning on simplifying some development setup of multiple `docker-compose.yml` by introducing virtual hosts locally. I looked around and decided to use [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) for the reverse-proxy (ability to set `VIRTUAL_HOST` for each service).

### Setup

To expose these on the host machine I went the route of `dnsmasq` and adding a `/etc/resolver/test/` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1`.

I went and put the above into action using a `dev/docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"

  dnsmasq:
    image: andyshinn/dnsmasq
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: --log-facility=-
    volumes:
      - ./data/dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
      - ./data/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxynet
```

The `data/dnsmasq.conf` file only contains `address=/test/127.0.0.1`.

I've also created an external network `proxynet` and use that as the default network for the docker-compose file(s) (`docker network create proxynet`). This then allows other docker-compose files and services to be linked to the proxy.

I have the following `proj1/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  proj1-web:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=proj1-web.test

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxynet
```

Having both these of these docker-compose files running (i.e., `docker-compose up`) I am able to access `proj1-web.test` from my local machine. Everything works as expected.

Now I want to be able to reference `proj1-web.test` in another container and have it resolve to the running container.

I'll create `proj2/docker-compose.yml` (similar to previous just different name):

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  proj2-web:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=proj2-web.test

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxynet
```

With everything running I can access both `proj1-web.test` and `proj2-web.test` from my local machine. I can successfully curl different services using between `proj1` and `proj2`: `docker-compose run proj1-web sh -c "apk update -qq; apk add curl -qq; curl -v proj2-web:8000"`.

### Problem

The problem is that I cannot curl the virtual host's name `proj2-web.test` from `proj1`: `docker-compose run proj1-web sh -c "apk update -qq; apk add curl -qq; curl -v proj2-web.test"`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: proj2-web.test/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to proj2-web.test port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to proj2-web.test port 80: Connection refused
```

Is there something I'm missing here? It appears the individual containers don't have access to the DNS being provided from `dnsmasq` to my local machine, I cannot figure out how to grant them that access. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way -- I am open to suggestions.

Comment: So you are expecting the proj2-web to be dnsmasq dns aware without configuring it to consume that DNS ?

Comment: Not familiar with the setup, are you expecting the proj2-web to be dnsmasq dns aware without configuring it to consume that DNS ? Also what tells the DNS service what IP to point to when a request comes for a specific domain?

Comment: @Bizmate I think that is the plan. I'm looking for a way to get the containers to use my host's DNS (as it works there), or to use the DNS+proxy inside the docker network. I'm not too familiar with Docker (or DNS/networking to boot), so I suspect I'm missing something critical here.

The interesting thing is I can successfully ping the container using `docker-compose exec proj1-web sh -c "apk update -qq; apk add curl -qq; ping -c1 proj2-web.test"`.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a solution which addresses my question. You can see the repository here for the tool:

https://github.com/scoremedia/dcdc

I also created a blog post detailing a bit of this: https://kevinjalbert.com/docker-compose-dns-consistency-dcdc/

Hopefully this helps others.